# Do mathematical objects have underlying types?

Tags: logic, soft-question, definition

I came upon this issue while I was trying to think about what "type" of object is $\mathbb R^n$ - is it a set, a vector space, an inner product space, an affine space, a metric space? Perhaps the simplest way is to define $\mathbb R^n$ as simply being an object of type "set", and then construct new objects such as the *vector space $\mathbb R^n$*, which possesses an additional structure by having the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication, or the *metric space $\mathbb R^n$*, which possesses the additional structure of a metric.

It seems often the case, at least in real analysis, however, that we wish to work with an object (denoted $\mathbb R^n$) which possesses both the algebraic structure afforded by being a vector space and the geometric structure afforded by being a metric space. While I can do all of the calculations, treating $\mathbb R^n$ as both a vector space and a metric space, I am troubled by the fact that I'm not sure which *type* of object I'm working with. Is it a metric space, or is it a vector space? Is it both? Neither? How should I think about this? (for both the "type" of $\mathbb R^n$ and for mathematical objects in general)

I added a few tags that I thought might be relevant (in areas I'm not quite familiar with), but mods should feel free to remove them if they're not appropiate.

Comment: This is symbol overloading, and should be clear from context. If it's not clear, then specify it.

Comment: You can approach mathematics in many different ways.

Comment: Somewhat often, these "joint objects" that have two seemingly disparate structures have a unification between the structures. For instance $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be thought of as a normed vector space. This way, although a metric has nothing to do with algebra, a norm *always* has something to do with algebra. Similarly, a topological vector space has the addition and scalar multiplication both being continuous, which creates a connection between the algebra and the topology.

Comment: I highly recommend looking at how such things are handled in proof assistants like [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) or [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/).  It will give you an appreciation for how much detail is suppressed, for better and worse, in virtually all mathematical presentations.

Comment: In the most common foundational setting, set theory, there isn't a real notion of "types." The statement "A is a B" is either represented as "A is in the collection of all B." So if you treat "B" as a type, $A$ doesn't have a "type" or even a reasonable list of "types."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Statements like that are actually where this sort of question usually comes from, in my experience. People hear things like that, and figure "OK, so everything's set theory, cool", and then they wonder why so little mathematics actually *looks like* set theory, as written.

Comment: @Ian It's not clear if that is criticism, but I was being very careful in my language - "most common."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I appreciate that. I also appreciate that you left it as a comment rather than an answer, because I actually don't think it really answers the question, but rather raises the further question of "why, if we could found things in set theory, do we not actually write that way"? Still, I do see the merit in your comment.

Comment: @T.Bongers The perspective you presented makes some sense out of this. So "$\mathbb R^n$ the set", "$\mathbb R^n$ the vector space", "$\mathbb R^n$ the metric space" are all different objects, with different types, but the same symbols are used to represent all of them - symbol overloading, as you pointed out. I guess the reason it's so common is that all of the objects mentioned involve, in one way or another, the set of $n$-tuples of real numbers?

Comment: Yes, and then the discussion after @T. Bongers occurred because you can think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as 'just' a set, and then add structure to make it a vector space, a metric space etc. But that's not the only foundation to build these different, related objects. In some ways the symbol overloading here isn't a bad thing; it just says that we're thinking of the most 'intuitive' or 'natural' metric space/ topological space/ etc. (which you work out from context) over the real $n$-tuples. And they're usually compatible which is nice.

Answer (score 3):

Putting things together into an answer and expanding significantly.

First, as T. Bongers stated, this is a form of notational overloading that is usually intended to be resolved by context.  The context may be either broad conventions ("standards") such as $\mathbb R^n$'s metric structure, canonical choices such as $\mathbb R$'s field structure, or the convention may be defined in the text you're reading.

Still, if we didn't want to rely on context what would we do and what does this overloading "resolve" to anyway?  The typical approach to be more explicit in informal (by which I mean "not machine checked") texts is to do the following:

$$\mathbb{R} \text{ is the set of real numbers} \\ (\mathbb{R},+,0) \text{ is the additive monoid of real numbers} \\ (\mathbb{R},\times,+,1,0) \text{ is the semiring of real numbers}$$

This clearly articulates the additional structure a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) and a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) have and what choices we are making here.  If we want to treat a semiring as a monoid, we'd have to explicitly forget the extra structure: $U_M(t,m,a,u,z) = (t,m,u)$ (note we'd also have $U_A(t,m,a,u,z) = (t,a,z)$, both $U_M, U_A : \mathbf{SemiRing} \to \mathbf{Monoid}$).  Similarly, $U : \mathbf{Monoid} \to \mathbf{Set}$ would be $U(t,m,u) = t$.  Compare this with typical statements like $U(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R$.

Being this explicit can often be clarifying and helpful.  For example, it's much easier to see and articulate the adjunction in $$\mathbf{Monoid}(FS, M) \cong \mathbf{Set}(S, UM)$$ than in $$\mathbf{Monoid}(FS, M) \cong \mathbf{Set}(S, M)$$  The former can easily be expressed with $F \dashv U$, the latter is awkward to write down without introducing $U$.

The tuple notation can also be very handy. Sticking with the above adjunction, if you want to explicitly define the counit, using the normal, implicit notation leads to some awkwardness and difficulty.  In the typical notation you'd be asked to define a natural transformation: $\varepsilon_M : FUM \to M$ natural in $M$.  The elements of $FUM$ for a monoid $M$ are just lists of elements of $M$.  We need to collapse that list into a single element by multiplying them all together by the monoid operation. $\varepsilon_M(ms) = \text{fold}(?,?,ms)$ but what do we put for the question marks?  It should be the multiplication and unit of the monoid, but what are they?  The free monoid construction has certainly forgotten them.  Moving to the more explicit notation, we see: $\varepsilon_{(M,\oplus,e)}(ms) = \text{fold}(\oplus,e,ms)$.

However, even the approach above is suppressing some aspects.  For example, what's the difference between a monoid and a commutative monoid?  There is no additional [structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property), just an additional property of the existing structure.  Taking a cue from type theory, the additional evidence we need that a [monoid](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Algebra.html#1154) is a [commutative monoid](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Algebra.html#1636) is a [*proof*](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Algebra.Structures.html#1180) that the operation is commutative.  Once we make that explicit, we should then make explicit the [evidence](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Algebra.Structures.html#935) that the operation is associative and unital.  It's extremely rare for mathematicians to treat proofs as mathematical objects, but this is exactly what modern type theories do.

The cost of all this explicitness, of course, is verbosity and bureaucratic distinctions that can clutter up what is trying to be demonstrated.